# How to swap contents of header tag - HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following:

```js
function changeFirst() {
  let p = document.getElementById("firstElement")[0].innerhtml;
  alert(p);
  if (p = "<h1>This is the 1st element</h1>") {
    document.getElementById("firstElement").innerHTML = "<h1>Changed first</h1>"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("firstElement").innerHTML = "<h1>Switched back first</h1>"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="firstElement">
  <h1>This is the 1st element</h1>
</div>

<button onclick="changeFirst()">Change first element</button>
```

I basically want the button to alternate the contents of the `firstElement` div. Why doesn't this work?

Thank you

Comment: did you look at the console errors? they're pretty self explanatory. you're missing the closing curly on your function, which may have just been a copy error, and then you're treating the results `getElementById` like an array when that function only returns a single element.

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` in the function block from above.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison. In `if (p = "<h1>This is the 1st element</h1>")`. And no `[0]` in `getElementById("firstElement")[0]`

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to copy the closing bracket

Comment: side note: i would rather add/remove some class, check if it´s there or not and add text accordingly, instead of comparing with the text directly.

Comment: Probably due to the very basic issues such as assignment instead of comparison

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById returns ONE element

Also = is assignment, you want == or === for comparison

Could you possibly mean this:

```js
function changeFirst() {
  let h = document.querySelector("#firstElement h1");
  h.textContent = h.textContent==="This is the 1st element" ? "Changed first" : "This is the 1st element"
}
```

```html
<div id="firstElement">
  <h1>This is the 1st element</h1>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="changeFirst()">Change first element</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is exactly what you asked for. You were close.

1) when including javascript, you can just use script tags and it will work fine, when you use JSON or JQuery, that's when you have to use an include tag of a .js file. javascript code can be notated with script type = text/javascript.

2) when making a comparison in javascript: use three equal signs (===)

when making a non variable type-sensitive comparison: use two equal signs (==)

when setting a variable: use one equal sign (=)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-operator-in-javascript/

3) When calling dynamic header, it is not an array, so you don't need [0], you are just comparing the innerhtml of the dynamic header div and it is only one header, arrays are for multiple things. Keep working on code, as you seem to have a good start, and made some minor syntax errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="changeHeader()">Click me</button>

  <div id="dynamicHeader"><h1>Hello World</h1></div>

  <p>Clicking the button changes the header.</p>

  <script>
    function changeHeader() {
      if (document.getElementById("dynamicHeader").innerHTML === "<h1>Hello World</h1>") {
        document.getElementById("dynamicHeader").innerHTML = "<h1>Goodbye World</h1>";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("dynamicHeader").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not use OPs example?

Comment: Added another answer doing exactly what he wanted.

Comment: Why pollute. And why remove the snippet I made. Just change your existing answer and keep the snippet so there is a [mcve] to play with

Comment: using two equal signs is bad practice, use three equal signs for typesafe comparison instead.

Comment: updated code to include three equal signs and added link to explanation. For this small comparison, 2 equal signs will work. 3 equal signs is safer because if you were comparing two different variable types, it would properly return the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Here I introduced a flag and switched it to check content.

```js
var changed = false;
function changeFirst() {
 
  if (!changed) {
    changed = true;
    document.getElementById("firstElement").innerHTML = "<h1>Changed first</h1>";
  } else {
    changed = false;
    document.getElementById("firstElement").innerHTML = "<h1>Switched back first</h1>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="firstElement">
  <h1>This is the 1st element</h1>
</div>

<button onclick="changeFirst()">Change first element</button>
```

Comment: can you explain why it is needless?

Comment: I haven't downvoted but you should explain your changes, e.g. fixing the syntax errors.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I have explained it.

Comment: @j08691 if thats the reason. they need some mental check ups.

Comment: @mplungjan will you suggest to use a condition which contains tags and other stuffs? in reality what if it was a more longer?

Comment: using a class would also be ok, but the solution with a variable is much better than using the long text directly imho. you should use `let` instead of `var` though, but that´s just nitpicking :)